# Micronuat Data Entity findAll order by createddate desc

Tags: jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I using micronuat Data with JPA to access the MySQL table.  findall return all the data, now I want sort the output by `createdat` datetime filed.

```
@Get("/")
List<Book> all() {
    return bookRepository.findAll()
}
```

How to sort this value by createdat field?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to sort this value by createdat field?

A simple way is to add a `listOrderByCreatedat()` method to your repository.

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    List<Book> listOrderByCreatedat();
}
```